# Local source server VS2013exp cannot find source

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, nuget-server, proget

I've installed a internal proget server, "proget" as a standalone service (not IIS).  I can push -Symbols packages to it just fine, and use the dependencies.  However, I cannot step into the dependncy.

I'm using all default settings my default feed was setup with.  When I load http://proget.domain.local/ I can see the UI of proget just fine.

I followed http://inedo.com/support/kb/1036/using-progets-symbol-server over and over to see if I missed a step.

- I'm using http://proget.domain.local/symbols/Default for my source server
- unchecked "enable just my code"
- unchecked "require source files to exactly match original version"
- checked entire tree of "enable source server support"

When I build my project, my packages//lib does not contain the PDB file.  From what I have read, although counter-intuitive to me, this is how the source server will be used, due to the lack of PDB.  Is that right?

When I run fiddler, I do see a successful attempt to retrieve the PDB
200 OK http://proget.domain.local/symbols/Default/domain.core.api.utils.pdb/CE8120175941480FBFD0F51EE58AE1991/domain.core.api.utils.pdb

with the following lines wrapped in much binary data.  I have no idea if anything is useful in here or not.

```
    VERSION=2
    INDEXVERSION=2
    VERCTRL=http
    SRCSRV: variables ------------------------------------------
    SRCSRVVERCTRL=http
    PGSERVER=http://proget.domain.local/source-files
    PGFEED=Default
    PGPKGID=domain.core.api.utils
    PGPKGVER=1.0.0.8
    HTTP_EXTRACT_TARGET=%pgserver%/%pgfeed%/%pgpkgid%/%pgpkgver%/%var2%
    SRCSRVTRG=%http_extract_target%
    SRCSRVCMD=
    SRCSRV: source files ---------------------------------------
    e:\jenkins\workspace\test-msbuild-jenkins
```

The same problem exists when I go into proget and uncheck "automatically strip symbols" from the feed.

I do not receive any errors, simply the source not found, browse... dialog when I attempt to step into the dependency.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I've exhausted google.

Comment: PDB/SrcSrv is really, really tricky. It's an arcane, undocumented format and has a lot of 10-year old bugs that need to be worked around. Use a really simple package, try to see where things are falling apart (indexing, retreiving, visual studio, etc).  I'd suggest to take a look at Inedo's [QA #1885](http://inedo.com/support/questions/1885) to get some more debugging strategies.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very close to my issue so even though they've already solved that particular problem, perhaps I can as you said, use those same tools to find a different problem.  This package I am using is about as simple as I can get, one liner static function in a c# class library as the nuget dependency (what I am trying to step into), and a one liner console program of what is using the nuget dependency.